# Knockout with Jquery UI datepicker date is not displaying on submit button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, datepicker, submit

I have added Datepicker UI. Every time i add new gift Date textbox working fine with datepicker.

But when i click on submit button, It's not displaying date in json format.

Please see this link for example[ http://jsfiddle.net/pakpatel/5p6Uz/2/ ]

Could anyone explain me what am i doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the relevant code *in* the question :)

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker please see the link [ http://jsfiddle.net/pakpatel/5p6Uz/4/  ] It's working now, But if you can help me out with this question. If first date choose like 10/12/2012 then on second date shouldn't be before 10/12/2012, Has to be after in datepicker. something like 10/13/2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind value:

```
<input class='required' data-bind='datepicker: choosedate, value: choosedate, datepickeroptions: { mindate:  new Date()  }, uniquename: true' />
```

Comment: it's work after your Answer, Thanks Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/pakpatel/5p6Uz/4/